# Milnor number/Mapping Degree

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, singularity, singularity-theory

I am reading in John Milnor's Book *Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces* and struggle to do a similar computation he did.

Namely, how can I compute **explicitly** the Milnor number $\mu(f)$ on the Milnor Fiber F, given by a polynomial relying on the definition with the mapping degree, i. e. the degree of the map $z \mapsto \frac{\nabla f}{\|\nabla f\|}$ on $S_{\epsilon}$, e. g. for $f(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4):=z_1z_4+z_2^3+z_3^3+z_4^5$? (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor_number#Geometric_interpretation)

Hereby, the degree of a mapping $f:S^n \to S^n$ is understood by means of homology, i. e. the unique number $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f_*(x)=dx$, where $f_*$ is the induced function in homology.

I know that $deg(z^n)=n ~ \forall n$. Could this be helpful? Or should I first write $\frac{\nabla (f(z)}{\| \nabla f(z) \|}$ in polar form?

Also, maybe this post [Number of roots the degree of the map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320521/number-of-roots-the-degree-of-the-map) could be helpful. (Here, is it applicable at all despite the gradient?)

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I am reading in John Milnor's book _Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces_ where he introduces this definition.

Comment: Ok, great, but you still need to do a bit more here: you need to [edit] that information in to the question instead of posting it in the comments, and you need to explain more about where your specific problem is when you try to compute. Where is your specific difficulty? Can you write down the map $z\mapsto \frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f||}$? Do you know the definition of degree? Where exactly are you stuck? Remember: instead of answering my questions in the comments, [edit] these things in to your post.

Comment: Your comments suggest that you think you're working in $\Bbb C$, not in $\Bbb C^4$ (i.e., on $S^7$). I recommend you read further in the wiki article you linked and see the algebraic approach.